# MATLAB interop server (automation server) is available with Runtime libraries?

Tags: matlab, com-server

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to use the MATLAB COM server (automation server) without installing the whole MATLAB package (but only the runtime libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that MATLAB COM server is Matlab engine and runtime libraries are MCR.

And the answer is:
**No**, because `MCR` is available to re-distribute freely whereas `Matlab` requires a license.

This is taken directly from [here:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29148.html)

> You must use an installed version of MATLAB; you cannot run the MATLAB engine on a machine that only has the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR).

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected - but it would be good to have a direct confirmation from someone who tried